# $\mathbb{E}(X)$ for joint pdf where $0<y<x< \infty$

Tags: probability, covariance, density-function

On this problem, X and Y have joint pdf

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{2y}{x^2}e^{-x} & ,0 < y < x<+ \infty  \\ 0 & , \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

So I'm supposed to find $\mathbb{E}(X)$ in order to find the covariance

$\mathbb{E}(Y)$ kinda makes intuitive sense, as you integrate $y$ from $0$ to $x$ and $x$ from $0$ to $\infty$, but I'm confused about what the bounds for the double integral of $\mathbb{E}(X)$ would be.

Apparently the answer is $1$.

Thanks!

Comment: You wrote the bounds for double integral: $y$ from $0$ to $x$ and $x$ from $0$ to $\infty$. What is your question?

Comment: So I'm assuming my x-integral would go from x=y to ∞ and my y integral would go from 0 to ∞, and I'd just compute the x-integral first to get it in single-variable terms?

Comment: @NCh I'm asking about the E(X) integral instead of the E(Y) integral

Comment: By the way, please use MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JonnathanBaquero, $EX$ differs from $EY$ by only the multiplier $x$ vs $y$ and not by integral bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the $E(x)$, we just need to find the probability distribution of $x$. Now you know the joint probability of $x$ and $y$, so you can get the probability distribution of $x$:$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{x} \dfrac{{2y}}{x^2} e^{-x}dy=\dfrac{{e^{-x}}}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x}\!y^2\,\mathrm{d}y=e^{-x}$. Then $E(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}xd{-e^{-x}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}d{-e^{-x}}=1$!

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$f(x,y)=   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{2 y }{x^2} e^{-x} & 0 < y < x < \infty \\
      0 & \mbox{otherwise} 
\end{array} 
\right. $$

We want to compute the marginal distribution of $X$. We get,

$$f(x) = \int_0^x \frac{2 y}{x^2}e^{-x} \, dy = e^{-x}.$$

Observe that

$$E[X] = \int_0^{\infty} x f(x) \, dx=\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-x} \, dx = 1$$

Or, similarly, using a double integral...

$$E[X]=\int _0^{\infty }\int _0^x x \frac{ 2y  }{x^2} e^{-x}dydx$$

Answer (score 0):

Just as you wrote the integral bounds,
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty \int_0^x x\cdot \frac{2y}{x^2}e^{-x} \,dy\, dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}e^{-x} \cdot x^2 \,dx= \int_0^\infty xe^{-x} \,dx =1.
$$
If you want to integrate by $x$ first, then by $y$, you get [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) which is not an elementary function:
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty x\cdot \frac{2y}{x^2}e^{-x} \,dx\, dy =  \int_0^\infty 2y \underbrace{\int_y^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \,dx}_{-\text{Ei}(-y)}\, dy.
$$
So, this way is improper.